# How to remove rotations from view matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

My question is about removing rotation from the view matrix. Removing translations is easy but I couldn't find any way to remove the rotation from a matrix. Is there any way to remove rotation from the view matrix.

The camera rotates around the y-axis so view matrix also and affects reflection.

In vertex shader my code is

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 ModelSpaceVertexPosition;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 ModelSpaceVertexNormal;

out vec3 reflectnormal;
out vec3 reflectposition;

uniform mat4 ModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

void main(){

reflectnormal =  ( ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(ModelSpaceVertexNormal,0)).xyz;//mat3(transpose(inverse(ModelMatrix))) * ModelSpaceVertexNormal;
reflectposition =  vec3(0,0,0) - ( ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(ModelSpaceVertexPosition,1)).xyz;//vec3(ModelMatrix * vec4(ModelSpaceVertexPosition, 1.0));
gl_Position =  ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(ModelSpaceVertexPosition,1);

}
```

In fragment shader my code is

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 reflectnormal;
in vec3 reflectposition;

uniform samplerCube skybox;

out vec3 color;

void main(){   
    vec3 Rtest = reflect(-reflectposition, reflectnormal);
    vec3 EnvironmentReflection = vec3(texture(skybox , Rtest));
    color = EnvironmentReflection;
}
```

which gives me nice view of [image]

but the problem is rotation. when I rotate camera reflection also rotates with the camera.

[image]

[image]

How can I remove rotation from reflection?

Gif video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBuFa.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `skybox` contains a cubemap with respect to world space. Hence you have to compute the reflection vector (`Rtest`) in world space.

---

One possibility is to transform `Rtest` from view space to world space. This can be done by the [`inverse`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/inverse.xhtml) view matrix in the fragment shader:

```c
uniform mat4 ViewMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 Rtest = reflect(-reflectposition, reflectnormal);
    vec3 Rtest_world = inverse(mat3(ViewMatrix)) * Rtest;
    vec3 EnvironmentReflection = texture(skybox, Rtest_world).xyz;
    color = EnvironmentReflection;
}
```

---

Anyway you should avoid to transform a direction vector in the fragment shader. It is *cheaper* to do the computation in worldspace and to compute `reflectnormal` and `reflectposition` in world space rather than view space.
You have to the get the position of the camera in world space, for the computation of the view vector. The position can be get by the translation of the inverse `ViewMatrix`:

```c
vec3 camera_world = inverse(ViewMatrix)[3].xyz;

reflectnormal   =  (ModelMatrix * vec4(ModelSpaceVertexNormal,0)).xyz;
reflectposition =  camera_world - (ModelMatrix * vec4(ModelSpaceVertexPosition,1)).xyz;
```

---

Note, the view matrix transforms from world space to view space. Hence the [Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) view matrix transforms from view space to world space. The inverse view matrix is the matrix which defines the position and orientation of the camera in the world, thus the translation of the inverse view matrix is the position of the camera in the world.